# Show tooltip in Autocomplete dropdown items using Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vue.js and Vuetify

Problem - To show tooltip on each dropdown item in v-autocomplete

Solution - added v-tooltip component in item template

Code:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [{
        value: 0,
        text: "Matthews Webb"
      },
      {
        value: 1,
        text: "Teresa Ward"
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        text: "Cervantes Swanson"
      },
      {
        value: 3,
        text: "Helga Cooper"
      },
      {
        value: 4,
        text: "Solomon Jensen"
      },
      {
        value: 5,
        text: "Eliza Delgado"
      },
      {
        value: 6,
        text: "Dickson Parks"
      },
      {
        value: 7,
        text: "Etta Glenn"
      },
      {
        value: 8,
        text: "Alma Durham"
      },
      {
        value: 9,
        text: "Rosemary Conner"
      }
    ],
    selected: []
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-autocomplete :items="items" v-model="selected" clearable multiple>
          <template v-slot:item="data">
            <v-tooltip right>
              <template slot="activator" slot-scope="{ on }">
                <v-list-tile-action>
                  <v-checkbox v-model="selected" :value="data.item.value"></v-checkbox>
                </v-list-tile-action>
                <v-list-tile-content>
                  <v-list-tile-title v-html="data.item.text" v-on="on"></v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile-content>
              </template>
          <span>{{ data.item.text }}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          </template>
        </v-autocomplete>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Problems after implementing the solutions:

1. Checkboxes are not clickable or item cannot be selected if clicked on the checkbox
2. On searching the item some of the checkboxes shows selected

Vue Version - 2.6.12

Vuetify Version - 1.5.24

Is there any other way to show tooltip on autocomplete dropdown items without disturbing the functionality or is there any mistake in my solution

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

The `v-input--selection-controls__ripple` Div overlaps the input box of the selection control; hence binds to the click instead.
To fix this I applied a simple CSS Hack. Conceptually position it above by using `position` and `z-index:-10` for the div.
that is illustrated with edits marked below as `/* <--------------- */`

```html
<div class="v-input__slot">
    <div class="v-input--selection-controls__input">
        <input aria-checked="false" role="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" style="
        position: relative; /* <--------------- */
        ">
        <div class="v-input--selection-controls__ripple" style="
        position: absolute; z-index: -10; /* <--------------- */        
        "></div>
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon material-icons theme--light">check_box_outline_blank</i>
    </div>
</div>
```